# Is my handwriting (hiragana) understandable?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

[image]

Hello!

I'm a beginner in Japanese and so far I have kind of memorised hiragana. It would help me a lot if anyone could take a look at my handwriting and tell if it is understandable.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Try improving your ほ, や, ら and り characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but "ya" and "ri" are badly written.